# Technical reasons to write sql query into a file instead of executing it?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

What the title says. I am reading some old code and there is a part where a lot of data is read in, but instead of directly writing it into the database an ascii file with a lot of sql INSERT queries is created and this file is than delivered to the sql-server. Why would anyone do that when you can just execute the queries right away? My understanding is that this can only hurt performance? Or is there a good reason to do this?

Comment: yeah, it definitely hurts the performance. may be it was a way of debugging database queries or measuring their performance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the idea was to keep track of changes to the database on a time-slice-basis or have a pre-commit-backup? distribution on multiple servers? debugging is a good guess as well. anyways, there are better ways to do those things.

Answer (score 1):

One could say there are three ways to do lots of `INSERTs`:

- One row at a time from code, and one per transaction.
- Batched `INSERT` statements, with at least 100 rows per insert.
- `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`

The first is the slowest, the last is the fastest.  There is probably more than a factor of 10 in performance.

But what you described sounds like a file full of 1-row `INSERTs`.  That does not help performance, but it might be more convenient for the programmer.

If that set of `INSERTs` is all one InnoDB transaction, then it ranks somewhere between the first and second bullet items above.